# Create a folder with the creation time as prefix (C++)

Tags: c++

For each execution of the program I need to create a new folder that contain the date and time of the creation of the folder as prefix.
for example if I execute the program at Date1Time1 the folder name will be Date1Time1_Folder,
after a few minute Date1Time2 the name will be Date1Time1_Folder

is there a way to do this stuff ?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look at std::file_system for dealing with creation of directories and std::chrono for everything related to time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the date and time:

```cpp
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
```

Then you need to format it to a style you want, I went for displaying day of the month and minute of the hour. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) for how to format it.

```cpp
// format date and time
std::ostringstream date_and_time_ss;
date_and_time_ss << std::put_time(&tm, "Date%dTime%M");
```

Finally you need to create the directory:

```cpp
std::filesystem::create_directory(date_and_time_ss.str() + "_Folder");
```

---

Example output on 12th of November at 7:00pm:
`Date12Time00_Folder`